# Pythonic shorthand for keys in a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, python, key

Simple question: Is there a shorthand for checking the existence of several keys in a dictionary?

```
'foo' in dct and 'bar' in dct and 'baz' in dct
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> all(x in dct for x in ('foo', 'bar', 'qux'))
False
>>> all(x in dct for x in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
True
>>>
```

It saves you a whopping 2 characters (but will save you a lot more if you have a longer list to check).

Comment: Accepting this answer thanks to the inclusion of useful links. :)

Comment: …although it repeats @unutbu’s earlier answer.

Comment: @flying sheep: There were no answers when I started typing mine. I guess unutbu started and finished typing while I created positive and negative examples and added some linked references. [i.e. I didn't copy his homework ;-)]

Comment: @John: If you put it this way, all right. Although two handy keyboard shortcuts should have helped you with the second example. Also: Who can’t type python.org’s links from the brain? We all have it under our pillow! ;)

Comment: @flying sheep: I'll try to type faster in future!

Comment: the useful links are broken :(  pls fix :)

Answer (score 8):

```
all(x in dct for x in ('foo','bar','baz'))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
{"foo","bar","baz"}.issubset(dct.keys())
```

For python <2.7, you’ll have to replace the set literal with `set(["foo","bar","baz"])`

If you like operators and don’t mind the performance of creating another set, you can use the `<=` operator on the set and the dict’s keyset.

Both variations combined would look like:

```
set(["foo","bar","baz"]) <= set(dct)
```

Finally, if you use python 3, `dict.keys()` will return a setlike object, which means that you can call the operator without performance penalty like this:

```
{"foo","bar","baz"} <= dct.keys()
```

Comment: This is a neat alternative, and demonstrates IMHO that TIMTOWTDI is inescapable; unfortunately, `set` in <= 2.6 does not take `*args` - you need to pass a sequence explicitly (another set of brackets).

Comment: This will be O(n) instead of O(1) for the others. You don't even have to be Dutch to see how horrible this will be if the dict is very large.

Comment: Thanks for the error in the set constructor call and for mentioning the operator. I don’t think that O(n) hurts in the OP’s case, though, since he’s going away from manually checking each key :)